# How to change content by consecutive button click?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to change textbox content as per click by the button. For example,

For first click of a button, `a` should be the content. For second click of a button, `b` should be the content. like `T9 Keyboard`.

My code, only shows `a` no other letters are being displayed.

My Code;

```
private void buttonFor1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var count = 0;
        count++;
        if (count == 1)
        {
            messageText.Text = "a";
        }
        else if (count == 2)
        {
            messageText.Text = "b";
        }
        else if (count == 3)
        {
            messageText.Text = "c";
        }
    }
```

Comment: just make `count` global variable, and when you reach last case start over `if (count == 3){ messageText.Text = "c"; count=0;}`

Comment: can u please explain your comment in C# coding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count=0;
    function Button_Click()
        {
            count++;            
            var txtBox=document.getElementById('txtAlpha');
            if(count==1)
            {   
                txtBox.value="a";
            }
            else if(count==2)
            {
                txtBox.value="b";
            }
            else if(count==3)
            {
                txtBox.value="c";
            }
        }
</script>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="Button_Click()"/>
<input type="text" id="txtAlpha"/>
</html>
```

Is this what you want.If this is what you wish to achieve you can replace the if 
else clauses with the ascii values of a/b/c accordingly,

1 will get converted to a, 2 will get to b etc.

In C# as per your request:

```
 static int count=0;// Global Variable declare somewhere at the top 

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "a";
            }
            else if (count==2)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "b";
            }
            else if (count == 3)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "c";
            }
        }
```

Hope you got my point!!

Cheers!!!

Comment: this is in JavaScript. I expected the answer in C#

Comment: Hey dear!!!

I think you didn't see the code carefully. In my code the 
var count is initialized outside the function click.

and in your case you have it inside the function,
so every time the button gets clicked the variable gets reinitialized. See my corrected answer


cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (messageText.Text == "")
            messageText.Text = "a";
        else if(messageText.Text == "a")
        {
            messageText.Text = "b";
        }
        else if (messageText.Text == "b")
        {
            messageText.Text = "c";
        }
        else
        {
            messageText.Text = "";
        }
    }
```